# Does View.doOnAttach callback guarantee that findViewById will return the view?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I create `FrameLayout` programmatically. I give it unique id - `myFrameLayoutId` - and apply `View#doOnAttach` listener, and then add to the hierarchy.

Within the listener I perform an operation, which relies on `findViewById(myFrameLayoutId)`. I've begun receiving very rare crash, which implies that `findViewById(myFrameLayoutId)` returns `null` sometimes.

Thus I wonder:

- Does call to the `View.doOnAttach` callback guarantees that `View` is findable?
- If not, what is a correct way to postpone some action until the point, when the view can be found by the `findViewById`?

Comment: I dont think so, according to documentation onCreate(Bundle) is called after that.

Comment: @AlexRivas could you point me at the referenced documentation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Does the call to View.doOnAttach callback guarantee that View is findable?**

> No, the **doOnAttach** callback does not guarantee that the View is findable via **findViewById**. The **doOnAttach** function is called when the view is attached to a *window*, but it does not guarantee that the view hierarchy is completely set up or that the parent has updated its child references.

**2. What is the correct way to postpone some action until the point when the view can be found by the findViewById?**

> You can use `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener`. This listener is called before drawing a view. By this time, the view hierarchy should be fully established, so **findViewById** should work as expected.

Example:

```
val frameLayout = FrameLayout(context)
frameLayout.id = myFrameLayoutId

frameLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
    override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
        frameLayout.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this) // Important to remove after being called

        // By this time, the view hierarchy should be ready
        val foundView = findViewById<View>(myFrameLayoutId)
        
        // Your logic here
        
        return true
    }
})

// Add the frameLayout to your view hierarchy
```

**References:**

- The official Android documentation provides information on [ViewTreeObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver) and its various listeners, including the OnPreDrawListener.
- The doOnAttach function is a Kotlin extension function provided by the Android KTX library. The documentation for this can be found in the [Android KTX reference](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#view).